# How to display time in decimal format in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, decimal

Now, I have successfully display the time in "HH:mm" format, but I will need to change it to decimals. For example, the hours is 2.30 meaning 2 hours and 30 minutes, but I need it to be 2.5 meaning 2.5 hours. Please help. Below is my code:

```
Local NumberVar HoursDiff;
Local NumberVar MinutesDiff;
Local NumberVar SecondsDiff;
Local StringVar strOut;

SecondsDiff := DateDiff('s',{Invoicing.TimeFrom},{Invoicing.TimeTo});
HoursDiff:= SecondsDiff  \ (60 * 60);
SecondsDiff  := SecondsDiff  MOD (60 * 60);
MinutesDiff:= SecondsDiff \ 60;

strOut := strOut & CStr(HoursDiff,0)& '.' & CStr(MinutesDiff,'00'); 
strOut
```

Comment: what should be the output if minutes in between 0 to 30 and 30 to 60 for e.g 24 and 56?

Comment: @Siva minutes divided by 60 to get the decimal value... for example if 10 h 56 m then we should have an output of 10.93 hrs or 10.9 hrs roughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following formula, I think it will work for you

```
timeVar time_value := CTime("2:30");//Time in HH:mm format
stringVar timeString := ToText(time_value);
numberVar time_in_min := ToNumber(Split(timeString,":")[1])*60 +   ToNumber(Split(timeString,":")[2]) ;
time_in_min/60;
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert this returned string value to time format using "time(strout)", then right click on formula field then select format filed option, it will opens a format editor in this select "date and time" tab. Then click on "customize" tab it will opens a custom style window.

in custom style window select time from order field in "Datetime" tab. then click on time tab and select which format you want.

Comment: Close, but not what I need. Thanks for the input.